# Javascript: how to convert text copied into textarea from any encoding to UTF-8?

Tags: javascript, utf-8, url-encoding

I have a simple html+js page with a `<textarea>`.
The user is supposed to paste some *text* inside it, and the page will use the pasted text as a GET parameter for a remote service url which expects UTF-8.

My current code is like this:

```
<body>
  <textarea id="editor"></textarea>
</body>
<script>
  var content = document.getElementById('editor').innerHTML;
  content = stripTags(content);
  content = decodeHTML(content);
  content = encodeURIComponent(content);
  var url = remoteServiceBaseUrl + content;
  window.open(url, '_blank');

  function stripTags(input) {
    return input.replace(/<(.|\n)*?>/g, '');
  }

  function decodeHtml(html) {
    var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
    txt.innerHTML = html;
    return txt.value;
  }
<script>
```

But it has trouble with - for example - `%0C` (`form-feed`) character found in some `Windows-1252` texts: when calling the url I am thrown the error `URIError: malformed URI sequence`.

So the question is: **how do I convert text to UTF-8, indipendently from the source encoding, with javascript?**

Comment: I don't think the problem is character encoding. The problem is that you can't have a formfeed in the path portion of a URL, URI-encoded or not. (You can in the query string or hash, but not the path.)

Comment: Side note: I assume you're **also** dealing with removing HTML content at the server end, since you can't ever trust client-side sanitation.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: 1st comment: my mistake, it was not a copy'n paste, I did rewrite the code to simplify it..., corrected. 2nd comment: I didn't think about it... You mean if it was in the query string part (after a '?'...), it should work? 3rd comment: The `remoteServiceBaseUrl` is an external service I don't control... So I will have to trust client-side sanitation, I assume the external service *do* sanitize requests... :-)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I do not have issues just with that form-feed character, but with `ª`, too (and many more... :-().

Comment: Yes, in the query string, it should be fine.

Comment: O.k., thanks. But I *have* to encode the string for a path portion of the url... :-(